# KDevelop VS Codelite

Tags: c++, ide, editor

After some months using IntelliJ for Java development I am amazed by how a good IDE can make easier your work/life.

As I usually program in C++, I am looking for an IDE which marks the difference as much as, from my point of view, IntelliJ do when compared to Eclipse.
That C++ IDE has to be compatible with Linux Environments and GCC and I prefer free software solutions.

Until now I have two candidates, Codelite and KDevelop, but I would like to have some feedback from developers who have worked with those IDEs for long time and/or in real projects.

Thank you.

Comment: @icodebuster There isn't any code in this question, so you shouldn't be adding code formatting to it.

Comment: Even if you don't prefer friendly and nice interface, lots of useful features, stable releases, simply take CodeLite for having a prompt support from developer himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used KDevelop for a while but it has a few ... issues (for example, it would segfault when I did "rm -fr *" in the build directory and attempted to rebuild in KDevelop, and it would segfault randomly while I was just editing code). I stopped using it when after a crash it would no longer start again.

A nice alternative is Netbeans for C++: it has a decent interface, is lighter weight than Eclipse and comes with sensible default settings (as opposed to Eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

If you are gonna do any coding in a UNIX environment I recommend taking some time to learn gdb, VIM (or Emacs), make, gcc and Makefiles. Chances are you will end up editing code on a server via ssh anyway. Having a good *IDEish* editor that does not depend on a graphical environment is golden in such situations.

YouCompleteMe, Syntastic and NERDTree are plugins for VIM well worth checking out.

Comment: I am used to Emacs and I have always said that there is not better development environment than an Unix terminal. Nevertheless, I have to admit that some IDE features go beyond when the time to help the developer comes. For example, it is a good point to have all your program/languages symbols and documentation indexed in your editor so that you don't really need to check reference books or webs continously.

Answer (score 1):

I have played with codelite a bit,  i have found its code completion to be acceptable, and tune able.

I am not nearly in to Linux programming as i wish i was at this point however.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not Visual C++, but I recommend checking out [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try codeblocks. I found this IDE very helpful for coding c++.